# Woocommerce: Remove the product description depending on specific content

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am looking for a way(hook) to hide a complete product description in woocommerce if it contains a specific text like "no description available".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you're looking for is something along these lines:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', function( $description ){
   if( false !== strpos( $description, 'no description available' ) ){
      return '';
   }
   return $description;
});
```

In other words - anytime the short description is displayed - check if it contains your string, and if so - return an empty string. Does that capture what you needed?

Comment: Hey cool. That's exactly it. Thanks a lot!